# Over extruding and feeding gear is grinding Ender 3 pro

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3, pla, extruder, troubleshooting

This issue is completely leaving me lost, my printer extrudes too much and leaves blobs yet the gear will just suddenly start grinding as soon as it begins to fill in the outline of my print. The grinding keeps going and the filament coming out just continues to blob leaving my prints a complete disaster. What confuses me is the fact that if the gear was grinding it would no longer feed more filament. The blobs proceed to then harden leaving my end essentially stuck dragging across cooled filament and pouring out even more of it into a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a setting mismatch between your slicer settings and the physical printer configuration. Diagnostic and informational questions follow:

- Can you provide more details of your machine configuration and your slicer settings?
- Are you using the Creality Slicer?
- Can you also provide more information about what you are attempting to print?
- Are you printing a downloaded design or your own?
- Have you printed successfully before? If so, the key question would be to ask what has changed.

There are a number of settings to check, but the first one that comes to mind is the filament diameter setting in the slicer. Secondary to that would be the flow percent. Check the diameter of your filament versus the setting in the slicer. The grinding of the gear makes me think that the physical filament diameter is larger than the slicer setting.  This could explain extruding too much material and producing "blobs" and also the grinding.

Comment: I am using cura as the slicer, I am attempting to print a extruder calibration test cube and I have tried several other prints to see if it is constant (it is), I have sucessfully printed the stock pig print on the ender with no problem twice now, so something tells me its the slicer yet I cant tell what the issue is.

Comment: I think that you are on the right track with looking at slicer settings. I am less familiar with Cura, but it has a filament diameter setting under "Materials." There are many possible settings to play with in Cura. As your issue is related to Cura, it could be good to mention it or use a tag for it in your question.

Comment: ive made sure the filament setting is the same as whats being fed to the printer, this all started recently on my last print.

Comment: Someone with more experience with Cura may be required to help troubleshoot. If you can print with a gcode from the Creality Slicer with the settings that you want (short of Cura's level of control/optimization), you could eliminate a hardware issue.

Comment: I made a unorthodox fix I just installed the creatility slicer and it works without any issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad that works. Happy printing.

Comment: Hi @chad and welcome to SE.3D Printing. SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your answer is inside a comment. This is not what the comment section should be used for. Please create an answer and read the [help], accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu. Please take the [about] and also have a look at the questions and answers to understand how SE works.